# How to filter array to keep only its duplicate elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array. I would like to create a new one from it which only consists of the duplicate elements. For example, before the array may look like

```
[[  3.   0.   1.   0.  12.   1.]
 [ 14.   0.   2.   2.   0.   3.]
 [  3.   0.   1.   2.   0.   3.]
 [ 12.   0.  14.   0.  12.   1.]
 [ 14.   0.   2.  12.   0.  14.]
 [ 15.   4.  13.  13.  14.  15.]
 [ 14.   2.  15.  13.  14.  15.]]
```

and after the operation I want it to look like

```
[[ 1.   0.  ]
 [ 0.   2.  ]
 [  3.  0.  ]
 [ 12.  0.  ]
 [ 14.  0.  ]
 [ 15.  13. ]
 [ 14.  15. ]]
```

Right now, I would do it using a for-loop, but maybe someone of you knows a smoother and quicker way.

Comment: If I got you well, you don't want a solution that requires a for loop, right ?

Comment: just to be clear, you are filtering by row since it's a 2d array, and you want to filter through only the elements that are non unique as in they show more than once correct?

Comment: He wants to keep once, the duplicated numbers of each list.

Comment: What's up with the inconsistent order? (Why `[ 1.   0.  ]` and why `[ 14.  15. ]`?)

Comment: the order  is not important here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a single numpy step because the length of the duplicates may change from line to line.

I suggest you do the folowing.

Define a function to find duplicates:

```
def dups(a):
    uniques, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    return uniques[np.where(counts > 1)]
```

Then apply it to each row of your array:

```
ans = [dups(row) for row in arr]
```

For the cases in which all rows have the same number of duplicates, you can make a numpy array out of `ans`:

```
ans = np.stack(ans)
```

For your example case, it prints:

```
[[  0.   1.]
 [  0.   2.]
 [  0.   3.]
 [  0.  12.]
 [  0.  14.]
 [ 13.  15.]
 [ 14.  15.]]
```